# Cox regression with two dependent expanatory variables

Tags: cox-model, predictor

I am doing a Cox regression to model how survival times of sick patients, after taking a certain number of pills. There are in total `10 different pills` patients can take. Some patients take one pill, some take two pills, but three pills is the maximum any patient can take. We measure how long each patient survives, and all measurements are right censored at 365 days.

I have a big problem choosing two of the covariates. It is a "known fact" that if you take three pills, you are likely two survive longer than those taking two pills, and even longer than those taking only one pill. So I have one covariate called $x_1$, which is the number of pills each patient take. But it has come to our attention, that some combinations of pills are actually decreasing survival time and are "bad" for the patients. Some combinations of pills are more frequent than others, and some combinations are actually non-existent. There are, as you understand, a lot of different combinations of 10 different pills, and also very important - `there are different combinations depending on how many pills you take` and all the types of combinations are gathered in the coviarate $x_2$, which gives me the model:

$h(t)=h_{0}(t)e^{\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2}$

But this gives me a lot of headache. Including the second covariate $x_2$ makes the first covariate $x_1$ redundant, but this covariate is "important" to me. I do not see how I can keep both, because they are obviously very correlated.

Is there any way of keeping my first covariate (number of pills), while including the second covariate (combination of pills)?

EDIT:

To summarize:

$x_1$ is number of pills taken, a categorical variable.

$x_2$ is combination of the 10 different types of pills taken. If the 10 different pills have different colours, some combinations could be: "red pill", 
"red pill + blue pill", "red pill + blue pill + orange pill" etc. This is also a categorical variable.

Comment: I think it would help to describe clearly what variables you have, and what is the purpose of the analysis. I thought you had 10 variables (dichotomous) at first but then it reduced to two variables?

Comment: I tried to be pretty clear about the specifications, but added a summary if it helps. There are 10 different pills avaiable to each patient, but he will choose 1,2 or 3 (variable 1, number of pills chosen). But also, which of the 10 pills he chose (the combination, variable 2) will matter. Now, I could just leave the count variable, and just use the combination variable (which implies the number of pills, being the count variable). But even though the combination variable "includes" the count variable, I would like to use both.

Comment: I could definitely be wrong. But it would perhaps be better to treat each pill as one variable, i.e. dichotomize each pill as yes or no, and then use interaction terms to model the potential effect-modifications of combinations.

Comment: You mean remove the count variable and just look at each pill as one binary variable, correct? In that case, I would not know how to model that type of interaction between all the pill variables, as my novice eye tells me it makees things very complex.